# Eclipse not allowing variable with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass a variable (Of class "Level") to another activity, but Eclipse is refusing to accept it.

```
Intent i = new Intent("LevelSpelen");
i.putExtra("speelveld", level1);
startActivity(i);
```

This is the error Eclipse gives me: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Level).

Why can't I pass this variable to another activity?

Comment: The error should be telling you exactly what is wrong, that you're calling the method incorrectly. Note that this has nothing to do with "Eclipse" and all to do with the method signature of your `putExtra(...)` method.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but how can I solve it? I can't find a signature for an Object

Comment: Because the method putExtra(String, Object) doesn't exists. However you could let your Level class implement the Serializable or Parcelable interface, and call `putExtra (String name, Serializable value)`

Comment: arguments (String, Level). which type of the level1 ??

Comment: I'm not familiar with your Intent class, but it seems that the putExtra requires a boolean second parameter, not a Level parameter. Unless there are other method over loads that are available.

Comment: Thanks @ZouZou! Implementing the Serializable interface solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the Serializable interface in your own class, it works.

Code for class

```
public class CustomClass implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Answer (score 0):

The putExtra method is normally used for primitive datatypes. If you want two activities to use an object with the same data, you could do one of two things:

1) Pass the attributes (as primitive data types in an Extra) of the object to the second activity and build an instance of the object there.

2) The second possibility would be a bit more interesting: instead of using the normal Application class for your application, you could use your own class that extends application. In that class, you could define your object as an attribute, so that it would be accessible to all application components.